# Xcode Fix Issue "Add the 'iCloud Containers' entitlement to your App ID not working

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud

I have an error message in an application target regarding iCloud.  Xcode gives me the ability to Fix Issue to "Add the 'iCloud Containers' entitlement to your App ID.  Seems to work when I first press the Fix Issue button - but when I move away to a different target and then come back the error message reappears.

It's like the fix doesn't stick.

In the past, I was able to split my application target into multiple targets for different variants and didn't have an issue. Now that I have split these new projects into additional variants, I am seeing the issue.

I'm working with Xcode 7.3.1.

Any ideas on what I can check to get this resolved?

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out.

Was a bad setting on the App ID.  When enabling iCloud, there are two options for Compatibility.  Setting the Compatibility option to "include CloudKit Support" fixed my issue.

Comment: This is insane!  I don't need CloudKit so I didn't select it.  Typical zero-documentation xcode stuff...  Thank you so much for posting this solution!